# Moving a menu in Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a menu with the following structure (simplified for illustration purposes):

```
Menu Bar
 |--File
 |   |--Save
 |   |--Exit
 |--Tools
 |   |--Tool Category 1
 |   |--Tool Category 2
 |   |--Tool Category 3
 |--Help
     |--About
```

I want to reconstruct this as follows:

```
Menu Bar
 |--File
 |   |--Save
 |   |--Exit
 |--Tool Category 1
 |--Tool Category 2
 |--Tool Category 3
 |--Help
     |--About
```

However, in Visual Studio 2008 Pro it won't let me drag these menu items other than reorganize them within the particular menu group they are already in. Is there a way for me to move them without completely rebuilding the menu bar? Note that there are actually many more menu items than those that I've shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it worked:

1. Right click on the menu item you want to move
2. Select "Cut" in the context menu
3. Right click on the menu strip where you want to move it
4. Select "Paste" in the context menu

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I wonder why drag and drop doesn't work, though.

Comment: This does 'work' but in my experience (VS2010) it drops the contents of the Click event (and other things too??). Cut works much better than Copy since it preserves the control's name etc., but I suspect hand-editing the code would work best.

Answer (score 5):

You can also go to the Designer Code for the Menu Items. You will find code similar to:

```
       this.mnuInfo.Items.AddRange(
          new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
             this.mniAddNewProject,
             this.mniAddNewWorkFlow,      
             this.mniDeleteProject
          }
       );
```

Add the menu item into which you want to move your existing menu items and then modify then move the items.

```
       this.mnuInfo.Items.AddRange(
          new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
             this.mniAddNewProject
          }
       );
       this.newMenuItem.Items.AddRange(
          new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
             this.mniAddNewWorkFlow,      
             this.mniDeleteProject
          }
       );
```

And that's it. I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm voting for this one--at least for menu items that are already fully set up and customized--because it seems less likely to lose stuff (see my other comment concerning the Click event).

Answer (score 1):

Just redo the menu from scratch, sometimes it's best to just start over! :-)

Comment: As I said, it's not a couple of items, there are a few dozen items that need moving. It would be convenient to drag and drop, or, as Vojislav suggested, cut and paste. Redoing from scratch would work, but as I pointed out in the question, I'd rather not.